# React Native number of components in one row

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I treat it like an exercise. There are 28 components. I want to have maximum 4 rows of components, where in each row there is maximum 7 components and minimum 1 depending on screen size (28 rows then). Could you help me how to accomplish this? I know I can use flex-wrap: wrap style but I want to have maximum 7 components in a row. Help me please with this as Im new to React Native and Flexbox.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'brown'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 2, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
.
.
.
    </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: How about `minWidth: \`${100/7}%\``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can't be solved in bootstrap way (column, row stuff etc). Flexbox lacks the capability to make specific number of components appear in a row depending upon screen size.

You need to use ListView such that ListView renders 7 components in a row. ListView's renderRow function iterates over an array and displays content of each index of that array in a row. So, at each index you need to define json  containing 7 attributes and return all these attributes in the form of an array to make them appear in a row.

In my project, I had to show 3 or less images in a row (as displayed in Media section of attached image) so I used the above mentioned approach to achieve this. Please find below my code. This might help you.

[image: In Media section, at most 3 images can appear in a row]

```
constructor() {
  // data saved in state
  this.state = {
    mediaFiles: [{image: "image link"}, 
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                 {image: "image link"},
                ],
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  var temp = [];

  //to ensure three images appear in a row
  for (var index     = 0; index < this.state.mediaFiles.length; index = index + 3) {
      temp.push({
        image1: this.state.mediaFiles[index].image,
        image2: (index + 1) < this.state.mediaFiles.length ? this.state.mediaFiles[index + 1].image : null,
        image3: (index + 2) < this.state.mediaFiles.length ? this.state.mediaFiles[index + 2].image : null
      });
  }

  this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource
       .cloneWithRows(temp)
  });
}

renderMediaThumbnails(rowData) {
  var mediaThumbnails = [],
    key = 0;

  for (var attribute in rowData) {
    if (rowData[attribute]) {
      mediaThumbnails.push(
        <View key={key++} style={Styles.imageWrapper}>
        <Image style={Styles.media} source={{uri: rowData[attribute]}} />
        </View>)
    }
  }
  return mediaThumbnails
}

renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <View style={Styles.mediaWrapper}>
      {this.renderMediaThumbnails(rowData)}
    </View>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={Styles.statusAndMedia}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Following are the styles:

```
mediaWrapper: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent: "space-around",

  marginVertical: 3,
},

imageWrapper: {
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: "#AE8B8C"
},

media: {
  height: 50,
  width: 85,

  resizeMode: "stretch"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad but I think my case is a bit different. With 28 elements given I want to have maximum 7 in a row and no more (even if screen size could accommodate more elements in a row). If the screen is small I would have less elements per row ( 1 is minimum of course). flex-wrap works fine but I don't know any way to tell it to stop on 7 (or rather on width which would be the width of those 7 elements).

Comment: In your case, what happens when screen has shorter width than width of all 3 pictures in a row ?

Comment: Yeah thats right. My solution might solve your 1st problem (max 7 in a row) but it won't do something different even if screen size gets shorter.
In my case, I've given fixed width to images and shorter screen size will only decrease the gap between the images.

Comment: I just ensured that no more than three elements appear in a row. If you want to display different number of items in a row on different screen size, you need to use Dimension class and get screen width on run time and then set styling on elements. This behavior can't be achieved alone with flex-box

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the solution. I set a width of a parent View to the with of screen or to the 294 (width of 7 elements + margins) if the screen size is larger. Maybe hardcoding it to 294 would be enough but Im not able to check it on small screen now.

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class Schedule extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'brown'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>
          <View style={{ margin: 1, width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
        </View>
    )
  }
};


export default Schedule;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    width: width > 294 ? 294 : width
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView is deprecated now , you can use SectionList or FlatList instead.